# Credit Card separated by comman - Regex - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, credit-card, regex-group

I've textfield which is accepting credit card numbers separated by comma(,)

Current Regex I'm using is :

```
/(\d{16})(?:,|$)/g
```

This regex allows :

```
1. 1234567891234567,1234567891234561,1234567891234564
2. 1234567891234567,1234567891234561,123456 (as well)
```

I need to apply regex which is 16 Digits (No specific Card number criteria but just 16 digits) separated by comma. 
No trailing or leading comma.
No number less or greater than 16 digits.
No alphabets or symbol.

Needs Help!

Comment: How will the numbers be separted by commas? Can you share a sample of the matched string? of your card number?

Comment: What's wrong with your current regex?

Comment: 1. 1234567891234567,1234567891234561,1234567891234564 --- > Should accept

2. 1234567891234567,1234567891234561,12345678 ---> should not accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^\d{16}(?:,\d{16})*$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/C1XHGr/2)

Comment: Only 16 digits to be matched followed by comma. Your regex demo shows 123,456,789,123,456,4 as match - which is not the case.

Comment: 1. 1234567891234567,1234567891234561,1234567891234564 --- > Should accept

2. 1234567891234567,1234567891234561,12345678 ---> should not accept